# Where does CKAN store the files pushed to datastore/filestore?

Tags: ckan

I am wondering where CKAN stores the files uploaded to the datastore/filestore.

I just set up the environment, and I tried to search on `/var/lib/ckan/default/storage`, but I can find only the icons. The CSV files that I uploaded in the tool are not there.

I searched in `/usr/lib/ckan`, but the files are not there. I could not find the CSV files anywhere else.

**Where are these files being stored?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### FileStore

By default, resource files are saved in the file system.

Inside CKAN `.ini` configuration file, the property `ckan.storage_path` points to the base folder where files are stored, for example:

```
ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan
```

That folder contains two more folders:

- `storage` contains the **uploaded group / organization images**
- `resources` stores the CSV (and PDF, XLS, ...) **resource files**, under two levels of folders

In order to find a specific resource file, look at its GUID:

- the first three characters of the GUID are the name of the **first-level folder**
- the following three characters of the GUID are the name of the **second-level folder**
- the remaining of the GUID (`-` characters included) is the **file name**

For example, if a resource GUID is `3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301`, it is stored on the file system as `/var/lib/ckan/resources/3F2/504/E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301`

### DataStore

If you configured the DataStore, CSV files are *also* stored in a database for easier querying.

Installing the DataStore involves adding in CKAN `.ini` configuration files something like this:

```
ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:pass@localhost/datastore_default
```

which state the database users, server and database name.

The data of each resource in the DataStore is contained in a database table whose name is the resource GUID.